# GWT+UIBinder+Gin+Guice+JDO+GAE example

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jdo, uibinder, gwt-gin

I'm trying to link all this technologies, but there are many isolated examples and I do not have enough experience to link them together

so my questions:
Whether there is a similar example?
Is it possible to use UIBinder with Gin?
Any recommendations to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know of such tutorials (a possible solution would be to get a book on GWT, but I don't know if there are any that deal with GWT 2.0 and Gin) - I'm afraid it's up to you to patch the knowledge from them together, that's what everyone has to do, right? ;) If you have some specific problems feel free to post a question about it, then we could help.
As for the **UiBinder** + **Gin** issue - I'm using both technologies and it's a breeze, but that's mainly because I'm also following the **MVP** (Model View Presenter) architecture/model - that way the view doesn't really has any dependencies and the Presenter does all the work. More on that here: http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html

Comment: Yeah, is it best practice to generate tons of code for simple application? :)

Comment: I don't know about you, but I use GWT for creating rather complex applications - ones were you benefit from using Java as your programming language (as opposed to the nightmare that is JavaScript - IMHO, of course). So I don't really care how much code it takes to write a "HelloWorld" app - on the long run that "more code" will help you (or someone else reading your code) understand what you wrote months to come and make testing/refactoring/further developing a breeze. If you don't see that, I recommend watching that presentation again (and/or reading/watching other materials related to GWT).

Comment: I agree that JavaScript nightmare exists and GWT simplify this, but I compare code amount, complexity and configuration understandability Guice+Gin+GWT+other "official" libraries with Spring+Wicket(or another) and my opinion that the first variant is more complex..
It seems that Google libraries need sufficient improvement in case of integration with each other. 
I would like to standards and out-of-the-box integration and not to spend time on understanding this "magic" ..

Comment: To each his/her own, eh? :) I actually hadn't had any major problems with using the "Guice+Gin+GWT+other "official" libraries" mix (including unofficial libraries like gwt-dnd or gwt-log). Adding a new module usually means just updating your project's module xml file and adding the jar to classpath - standard Java stuff, no "magic" here, IMHO. Of course, there's a whole Middle-earth's worth of magic under the hood, so that the whole Java -> JavaScript transition is as smooth as possible (but there are still some "leftovers" in the main code, such as `GWT.create`).

Answer (score 4):

The GWT blueprint that we use and works great for us.
http://sonymathew.blogspot.com/2010/01/gwt-jee-blueprint.html

Answer (score 4):

My own project is in an early phase, but it has all these technologies. You may want to take a look:
http://code.google.com/p/puzzlebazar/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice tutorial. The app is very simple but demonstrates all the basics you need.
http://reminiscential.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/building-a-gaegwt-application-using-the-best-practices-index/